# Plot multiple data using for loop, pyplot and genfromtxt

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am pretty sure this particular problem must have been treated somewhere but I cannot find it so I put the question.

I have 66 files with data stored in one single column. I wish to plot all data in a single plot. I'm used to do it with bash where acquiring and plotting data inside a loop is pretty trivial but I can't figure out in python.

thanks a lot for your help.

NM

Comment: You need to be more specific here: What kind of plot do you want? Are all files in the same directory? Also note that 66 groups of data are probably too many for a single, visually appealing plot. This question is very broad. Show us what you have tried so far and we kindly will try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it, although it will depend on how your data files are named.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

# Lets say your files are called data-00.txt, data-01.txt etc.
for i in range(66):
    data=np.genfromtxt('data-{:02d}.txt'.format(i))
    ax.plot(data)

fig.savefig('my_fig.png')
```